# Is it possible to pass state from Julia REPL to a Jupyter notebook via IJulia?

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook, ijulia-notebook

i'd like to open a Julia REPL in a terminal window, do some work, and then launch a Julia notebook via IJulia and notebook().  is there any direct way of passing variables and their values from the REPL, so they would be available in the notebook? or effectively equivalent, a way to access the REPL namespace from a notebook?   (i'd prefer to do this without creating temporary files or doing anything magical with memory.)